# Sybase to SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, migration, sybase

What is the fastest/best approach to load data from SYBASE to SQL server DB. I have tables with 500 million records. I tried using SSMA and BCP, both are taking over 24hrs. I tried using datastage (etl) methods but not of much help.
Thanks.

Comment: SSMA does have a batch size that you can fiddle with. I would say use SSMA latest version and change the default batch size. This is your best option.

Comment: What is your data load waiting for? IO on the target? CPU? You need to narrow this question down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> - Create Linked server which fetches data from Sybase to SQL. Source [Creating Linked server to SYBASE from SQL Server](http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-sybase-from-sql-server/)
> - Use ODBC connections to create an SSIS package which will fetch the data from SYBASE database onto SQL server. Check this [Extracting data
>     from Sybase SQL Anywhere using SSIS through ODBC](http://supun-biz.blogspot.com/2010/11/extracting-data-from-sybase-sql.html). Then Schedule
>     the above created package via SQL agent job to update data on SQL
>     server as per schedule which meets the requirement.